# Строковый поисковик

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Дана строка с текстом, который оторбражается в TextView. Как сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь вводил какой-то текст в другом текстовом поле, прога пробегала по тексту и выделяла, если находила этот текст. То есть чтобы работало как комбинация клавишь Ctrl+F.

Comment: Давайте уточним, вам под iOS или под OS X?

Comment: он в тегах айось пишет и считает что этого достаточно

Comment: @aknew во всех его вопросах `ios` в тегах, мало ли.

Comment: это да, тут что угодно может быть :)

Comment: я пишу ios потому что пишу под ios

Comment: @Sergey4590, я вам [накидал](https://gist.github.com/3149836) полу-псевдокод (не компилировал) - вот так можно сделать поиск. Правда, с выделением, как уже сказал @aknew, будет проблематично.

Answer (score 1):

Господи, прочитайте уже что-нибудь про разработку под айфон и посмотрите в хелпе

По вопросу - определяете свой контроллер как делегат для UITextView и определяете в нем метод

`- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView`

который будет вызываться при изменении текствью автоматически, ну а внутри уже пишете свой обрабочик - поиск или что еще хотите. Только по-моему выделить что-либо в тексте можно только в 6 оси с помощью attributedText, раньше не получится

Comment: Вы не правы, есть разные сторонние библиотеки, например, EGOTextView - http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/egotextview , FTCoreTextView - http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ftcoretextview . Не приходилось их юзать, но вроде делают то, что нужно.

Comment: Я имел ввиду родной сдк просто, но вы правы, надо было это уточнить

Comment: @Sergey4590, я вам [накидал](https://gist.github.com/3149836) полу-псевдокод (не компилировал) - вот так можно сделать поиск. Правда, с выделением, как уже сказал @aknew, будет проблематично.

Comment: @Violet , сильно не вчитывался, но разве оно не остановится после первого найденного вхождения? И, по-моему, с именами перменных в continueSearch напутали, а именно с search_range

Comment: @aknew, по идее, после первого вхождения будет отрабатывать continueSearch.   
search_range поправил, спасибо.